# What about hfs+ file system, `k3b` iso's and `growisofs` makes my blu-ray disk a coaster?

Tags: centos, hfs+, blu-ray

I backed up my MacBook using a Blu-ray burner on my CentOS server. When I try to mount the Blu-ray disk,

```
$ mount -t hfsplus /dev/sr0 /mnt/bluray
```

I get the error,

```
mount: no medium found on /dev/sr0
```

I *believe* the write was successful. I use a disk cataloger immediately after I burn every disk, and I have a catalog of the disk contents built from the mounted disk. I didn't give a thought to testing the disk since it was created from files copied to the server and the disk was clearly mounted during the cataloging step.

**How I made the backup**

Because I can't find a Linux package which plays nice with my Blu-ray drive, I use K3B to write an ISO from files copied to the CentOS server. Then I use `growisofs` to burn the Blu-Ray:

```
$ growisofs -Z /dev/sr0=mrwizard-archive-001.iso |& tee -a burn.log
```

Other Linux disks I've made will mount, so I know it's not the drive or drivers.

I'm 99% sure these are the steps I followed for this Mac OS backup. A grep in `history` shows I copied files to a directory with the same name as the Blu-ray disk image (also found in `history`). [UPDATE, just in case it wasn't clear, the backup was made four months ago in March]

There are numerous posts around the net talking about hfs+ and CentOS. These recommend the `kmod-hfsplus` package which I have installed. This package was necessary to transfer the files to CentOS.

Also, here's the tail from the `growisofs` log,

```
24024383488/24142608384 (99.5%) @1.8x, remaining 0:14 RBU 100.0% UBU  54.3%
24049221632/24142608384 (99.6%) @1.7x, remaining 0:11 RBU  99.8% UBU  43.5%
24078647296/24142608384 (99.7%) @2.0x, remaining 0:07 RBU 100.0% UBU  40.3%
24102764544/24142608384 (99.8%) @1.6x, remaining 0:04 RBU 100.0% UBU  45.7%
24126881792/24142608384 (99.9%) @1.6x, remaining 0:01 RBU  93.8% UBU  39.2%
/dev/sr0: flushing cache
/dev/sr0: closing track
/dev/sr0: closing session
:-[ CLOSE SESSION failed with SK=5h/INVALID FIELD IN CDB]: Input/output error.
```

This last error seems to be related to [something else](https://superuser.com/questions/462782/growisofs-warnings-when-writing-to-blu-ray-dual-layer-discs). As the OP in this post says the disk is mountable and readable even with this error.

Why `growisofs` made Blu-ray disk won't mount with Mac OS files?

Why would the disk appear to be mounted, only to fail mounting later?

What might happen as a result of these steps (k3b made iso, growisofs) and files from Mac OS, which might cause problems with this media?

What don't I understand about hfs+ file system, `k3b` iso's and `growisofs` which makes my disk a coaster?

```
$ dvd+rw-mediainfo /dev/sr0 long
INQUIRY:                [ATAPI   ][iHBS112   2     ][CL0J]
MODE SENSE[#3Fh]:
01: 00 80 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00
05: 40 05 08 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 96 00 00
    00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00
    00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00
    00 00
08: 04 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00
0D: 00 00 00 3c 00 4b
0E: 04 00 00 00 00 4b 01 ff 02 ff 00 00 00 00
18: 00 01 00 01 00 00 00 00 00 01 00 01 00 00 00 00
    00 00 00 00 00 01 00 01 00 00
1A: 00 03 00 00 02 58 00 00 04 b0
1D: 00 00 00 00 00 06 04 b0 00 00
2A: 3f 37 f1 77 29 23 21 14 01 00 20 00 21 14 00 10
    21 14 21 14 00 01 00 00 00 00 21 14 00 09 00 00
    21 14 00 00 1b 91 00 00 16 0d 00 00 10 8a 00 00
    0b 07 00 00 05 84 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00
    00 00
30: 2e 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00
GET [CURRENT] CONFIGURATION:
0000:   00 43 00 00 00 42 00 00 00 41 00 00 00 40 00 00
    00 2b 00 00 00 1b 00 00 00 1a 00 00 00 16 00 00
    00 15 00 00 00 14 00 00 00 13 00 00 00 12 00 00
    00 11 00 00 00 10 00 00 00 0a 00 00 00 09 00 00
    00 08 00 00 00 02 00 00
0001:   00 00 00 07 01 00 00 00
0002:   02 00 00 00
0003:   39 00 00 00
0100:
0105:   00 00 00 00
0108:   33 37 37 32 35 31 32 30 31 32 20 32 31 36 31 30
    37 35 30 30 34 34 34 20

//ERROR OUTPUT 
:-( no media mounted, exiting...
```

Comment: `no medium found` pretty much means the disc is not even recognized at all, regardless what's on it. see if you can read it with `dd`... if not then `mount` is not at fault here.

Comment: Ouch! No joy. And thanks for the test method. I didn't know about that one.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I see three problems here of which two were explainable immediately and one
needed more investigation by program dvd+rw-mediainfo.

First, you create an ISO 9660 filesystem and try to mount it as HFS+.
This is supposed to fail with "mount: wrong fs type, ...". Well, your
error message rather points to a medium problem before mount has a
chance to complain about the filesystem type.
Nevertheless, it looks as if you should leave out the arguments
"-t hfsplus".

Second, you ran into a known growisofs bug which is said to be harmless
  https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/dvd+rw-tools/+bug/1113679
It is caused by the fact that growisofs sees an unformatted BD-R when it
starts, later formats it by default, but in the end forgets that it is
formatted and issues a CLOSE SESSION command which is appropriate only
for unformatted media.
Workaround is to use growisofs option "-use-the-force-luke=spare:none"
or to format the BD-R by program dvd+rw-format before you give it to
growisofs or to apply the code fix shown in
  https://bugs.debian.org/cgi-bin/bugreport.cgi?bug=713016

The third and decisive problem is the operating system believing that
there is no readable medium in the drive. Program dvd+rw-mediainfo shows
why:

The drive does not report any of its supported profiles as "current".
A MMC profile is a set of features, typically associated to a particular
medium type. The drive announces to support BD-RE, BD-R, BD-ROM, DVD+R/DL,
DVD+R, DVD+RW, DVD-R/DL, DVD-RW, DVD-RAM, DVD-R, DVD-ROM, CD-RW, CD-R,
CD-ROM, and "Removable Disk". But none of them bears the "current" bit.

So the program concludes the same as the Linux kernel: No medium.

I get exact this reply from an ASUS BW-16D1HT if no medium is inserted.
With BD-R inserted, profile 0x0041 "sequential BD-R" is marked by the
byte "01" after "41":

```
GET [CURRENT] CONFIGURATION:
 0000:  00 43 00 00 00 42 00 00 00 41 01 00 00 40 00 00
```

That's the "current" bit which is missing in your drive's output.

So either the drive went blind or the medium is so damaged that the
drive does not recognize its type. Obvious remedy proposals are:
Try other drive or other medium.

Comment: as requested (see above)

Comment: Answer updated after xtian added dvd+rw-mediainfo output